# Android SQLlite Select by Numeric field

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a table:

```
_id  Data         Number
1    somestring     25
2    somestring     36
3    somestring     75
```

I need to get the Data string by the Number (Numeric field).
What I am doing:

```
 Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("tablename", new String[] {"_id", "Data", "Number"}, "Number" + "=75", null, null, null, null);
 if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(1);
        }
```

I never used a SQL database, so could you help me. I know i am doing something wrong. I just need to get the Data string by Number.

Comment: As a side note, `.moveToFirst()` should really be in an `if` statement, which skips getting anything if false (aka, there are no returned rows). And I assume your table is called "tablename" or your code differs to that shown?

Comment: I just used tablename here as an example. THe problem is, that this part of code: "Number" + "=75" gives me an Error. I think it's not the right way to SELECT from the db.

Comment: That is the where clause parameter, and would generate `"WHERE Number=75"` Which looks fine to me. Ideally with spaces for readability. Is Number a Text or Number field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cur = _db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE Number=?;", new String[] { String.valueOf(<number>) });

String result = "";

if(cur.moveToFirst()) {
    result = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Data"));
    cur.close(); // remember to close cursor object
}

return result;
```